# Is it possible to determine user gaze in ARCore / Sceneform (Augmented Reality) without using Unity?

Tags: android, augmented-reality, arcore, sceneform, android-augmented-reality

I can create a gazePointer in ARCore using Unity (as shown in: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/arcore-intro/#10), but is it possible to do the same without Unity (just using ARCore / Sceneform)?

The functionality I need to replicate in augmented reality is to detect the user's gaze on a predefined 2D reference image, and if the gaze is more than (say) 5 seconds, then a particular action should be implemented. We can assume that the "gaze" is at the absolute center of the user's view.

Note: I'm planning to do this in stereoscopic mode of a headset like Google Cardboard (i.e. with the phone camera uncovered).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ARCore Unity example you reference makes use of the Raycast function of the [Frame](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/unity/class/GoogleARCore/Frame) class of the ARCore Unity API. The equivalent function in the ARCore Sceneform API appears to be the hitTest function of the [Scene](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/sceneform/reference/com/google/ar/sceneform/Scene) class.